# how to convert date in oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime

I have a date in the format of:

```
27-MAY-09 12.00.00.000000 AM
```

I want to convert it to:

```
05/27/2009
```

I did `to_char(my_date_variable, 'MM/DD/YYYY')` however that gives me `character to number conversion error`

what can I do to convert this date?

my_date_variable is declared as:

```
my_date_variable VARCHAR2(40);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first convert `my_date_variable` from `VARCHAR2` to `TIMESTAMP`:

```
to_char(to_timestamp(my_date_variable), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: better off using an explicit format mask in the to_timestamp(my_date_var,'dd-mon-rr hh.mi.ss.ff6 am')